# Updating rows in a large table in sql server

Tags: sql-server, performance, update, query-performance

I want to update one large table that has 83,423,460 rows and growing.

The below query takes 8 minutes to execute successfully:

```
 UPDATE FPP_Invoice_Revenue
 SET    Till_Prev_Inv_Amt = Till_Prev_Inv_Amt_In_USD / 0.0285714286,
        Cur_Inv_Amt = Cur_Inv_Amt_In_USD / 0.0285714286,
        YTD_Inv_Amt = YTD_Inv_Amt_In_USD / 0.0285714286
 WHERE  SOW_Number = '20014378'
```

There exists one `clustered index`. I thought of disabling that index before updating and again will rebuild after update but that also did not work since rebuilding is taking a lot of time.

I have read somewhere this can be achieved by dividing into small parts,  but how can I divide the above query?

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FPP_Invoice_Revenue](
[Project_Code] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
[Project_Desc] [varchar](50) NULL,
[SOW_Number] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
[SOW_Desc] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Invoice_No] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Inv_Month] [int] NOT NULL,
[Inv_Year] [int] NOT NULL,
[Billing_Date] [smalldatetime] NULL,
[Doc_Currency] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Vertical] [varchar](255) NULL,
[Till_Prev_Inv_Amt] [numeric](24, 10) NULL,
[Cur_Inv_Amt] [numeric](24, 10) NULL,
[YTD_Inv_Amt] [numeric](24, 10) NULL,
[Till_Prev_Inv_Amt_In_USD] [numeric](24, 10) NULL,
[Cur_Inv_Amt_In_USD] [numeric](24, 10) NULL,
[YTD_Inv_Amt_In_USD] [numeric](24, 10) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_FPP_Invoice_Revenue] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Project_Code] ASC,
[SOW_Number] ASC,
[Invoice_No] ASC,
[Inv_Month] ASC,
[Inv_Year] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,       
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Execution Plan:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Adding an index on `SOW_Number` will allow SQL Server to very quickly identify the rows that need to be updated, without requiring a scan of the entire table (assuming a relatively small number of rows match the `WHERE` clause, making the index [highly selective](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/cardinality-versus-selectivity/)).

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_SOW_Number 
ON dbo.FPP_Temp_Revenue(SOW_Number)
INCLUDE (
        Till_Prev_Inv_Amt_In_USD
        , Cur_Inv_Amt_In_USD
        , YTD_Inv_Amt_In_USD
    );
```

Even though you have `SOW_Number` defined as part of the clustered index, it is not the *leading* column of the index, which means SQL Server must scan the entire index looking for rows that fulfill the `WHERE` clause.  Adding the three columns listed in the `INCLUDE` clause will allow SQL Server to not perform a lookup into the clustered index for those values, which it would otherwise need to do to as they are used in the calculations inside the `SET` clause.

I wouldn't normally suggest adding an index like this without evaluating the workload carefully; however I'm assuming you don't have any indexes other than the clustered index you identify in your script.  Adding a single index in this case will most likely make a very big difference to the performance of your update, without dramatically affecting other portions of your workload.

I setup a test-bed on my laptop so I could test the performance of adding the suggested index vs having no index on `SOW_Number`.

First, I created a new database `TestDB` for this test (I'm using SQL Server on Linux RC3):

```
USE master;
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.databases d WHERE d.name = 'TestDB')
DROP DATABASE TestDB;
GO
CREATE DATABASE TestDB
ON (NAME = 'TestDB_Primary', FILENAME = '/var/opt/mssql/data/TestDB_Primary.mdf', SIZE = 5GB, MAXSIZE = 10GB, FILEGROWTH = 1GB)
LOG ON (NAME = 'TestDB_Log', FILENAME = '/var/opt/mssql/log/TestDB_Log.ldf', SIZE = 5GB, MAXSIZE = 10GB, FILEGROWTH = 1GB);
GO

USE TestDB;
CREATE TABLE dbo.FPP_Invoice_Revenue(
         Project_Code varchar(10) NOT NULL
       , Project_Desc varchar(50) NULL
       , SOW_Number varchar(10) NOT NULL
       , SOW_Desc varchar(50) NULL
       , Invoice_No varchar(50) NOT NULL
       , Inv_Month int NOT NULL
       , Inv_Year int NOT NULL
       , Billing_Date smalldatetime NULL
       , Doc_Currency varchar(10) NULL
       , Vertical varchar(255) NULL
       , Till_Prev_Inv_Amt numeric(24, 10) NULL
       , Cur_Inv_Amt numeric(24, 10) NULL
       , YTD_Inv_Amt numeric(24, 10) NULL
       , Till_Prev_Inv_Amt_In_USD numeric(24, 10) NULL
       , Cur_Inv_Amt_In_USD numeric(24, 10) NULL
       , YTD_Inv_Amt_In_USD numeric(24, 10) NULL
CONSTRAINT PK_FPP_Invoice_Revenue PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    Project_Code ASC
    , SOW_Number ASC
    , Invoice_No ASC
    , Inv_Month ASC
    , Inv_Year ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,       
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];
GO
```

Next, I inserted 10,000,000 rows to have a sufficiently large table.  I know, this is a bit smaller than your table, but it provides enough data to make reasonable extropolations:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.FPP_Invoice_Revenue;
;WITH v AS (
       SELECT v.num
       FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9))v(num)
)
INSERT INTO dbo.FPP_Invoice_Revenue
SELECT Project_Code = CONVERT(varchar(10), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY v1.num, v2.num))
       , Project_Desc = CONVERT(varchar(50), CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(50))
       , SOW_Number = v5.num /* only 10 distinct values */
       , SOW_Desc = CONVERT(varchar(50), CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(50))
       , Invoice_No = CONVERT(varchar(50), CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(50))
       , Inv_Month = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY v1.num, v2.num) % 12
       , Inv_Year = 2009 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY v1.num, v2.num) % 8
       , Billing_Date = DATEFROMPARTS(2009 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY v1.num, v2.num) % 8, 1, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY v1.num, v2.num) % 12) + 1)
       , Doc_Currency = CONVERT(varchar(10), CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(10))
       , Vertical = CONVERT(varchar(255), CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(255))
       , Till_Prev_Inv_Amt = CONVERT(numeric(24, 10), 1)
       , Cur_Inv_Amt = CONVERT(numeric(24, 10), 2)
       , YTD_Inv_Amt = CONVERT(numeric(24, 10), 3)
       , Till_Prev_Inv_Amt_USD = CONVERT(numeric(24, 10), 4)
       , Cur_Inv_Amt_In_USD = CONVERT(numeric(24, 10), 5)
       , YTD_Inv_Amt_In_USD = CONVERT(numeric(24, 10), 6)
FROM v v1 --10 rows
       CROSS JOIN v v2 --100 rows
       CROSS JOIN v v3 --1000 rows
       CROSS JOIN v v4 --10000 rows
       CROSS JOIN v v5 --100000 rows
       CROSS JOIN v v6 --1000000 rows
       CROSS JOIN v v7;--10000000 rows
```

Next, I create the non-clustered index I've suggested above:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_SOW_Number
ON dbo.FPP_Invoice_Revenue(SOW_Number)
INCLUDE (Till_Prev_Inv_Amt, Cur_Inv_Amt, YTD_Inv_Amt);
```

This took about 1:20 to create on my laptop.

Now, the query:

```
UPDATE dbo.FPP_Invoice_Revenue
SET Till_Prev_Inv_Amt_In_USD = Till_Prev_Inv_Amt / 0.0285
    , Cur_Inv_Amt_In_USD = Cur_Inv_Amt / 0.0285
    , YTD_Inv_Amt_In_USD = YTD_Inv_Amt / 0.0285
WHERE SOW_Number = '6';
```

The test data is evenly distributed on 10 `SOW_Number` values; `WHERE SOW_Number = '6'` indicates we'll update 1,000,000 rows:

> (1000000 row(s) affected)

The actual execution plan for the update query:

[image]

The execution statistics for this:

> SQL Server parse and compile time:
>     CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
>   Table 'FPP_Invoice_Revenue'. Scan count 1, logical reads 6567261, physical reads 8920, read-ahead reads 209603, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> (1000000 row(s) affected)
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:
>     CPU time = 9376 ms,  elapsed time = 13689 ms.

As you can see from the above, the query only took around 14 seconds to update 1,000,000 rows.  If `SOW_Number` is more selective, the time required will be proportionally less.

As you've identified in your question, dropping the clustered index does not help increase performance of the update query.  Understand that all data in a table that has a clustered index is in fact stored in the clustered index.  Dropping and re-creating the clustered index will result in all 83 million rows being written to the log while data is moved in and out of the clustered index.  This is a *lot* of extra I/O that is not necessary for the update to succeed.

You have `SOW_Number` defined as a `varchar(10)`; if the content of that column is always actually 10 characters long you might consider modifying it to be a `char(10)` instead of `varchar(10)`, since that is actually more efficient.  Consider this for all the `varchar` columns you have.  Also, does `Vertical` actually need to be 255 characters long?  Presumably, `Inv_Month` and `Inv_Year` are actually not required to store up to 2,147,483,647?  You could likely convert those columns to `smallint` and save 4 bytes per row.  Keeping in mind the columns in the clustered index key are used (duplicated) in every non-clustered index, the space savings from right-sizing the data might be substantial.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than update, and most likely have to *keep* updating this table, why not create computed columns once?

They're simple calculations, and you can avoid using a trigger down the road.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.FPP_Invoice_Revenue
ADD Till_Prev_Inv_Amt_Comp AS Till_Prev_Inv_Amt_In_USD / 0.0285714286

ALTER TABLE dbo.FPP_Invoice_Revenue
ADD Cur_Inv_Amt_Comp AS Cur_Inv_Amt_In_USD / 0.0285714286

ALTER TABLE dbo.FPP_Invoice_Revenue
ADD YTD_Inv_Amt_Comp AS YTD_Inv_Amt_In_USD / 0.0285714286
```

You can decide whether to persist and/or index them, and any queries that currently use calculations that match the computed column definition should use the computed columns without changing your queries.

So something like this would also benefit:

```
SELECT 1/0 
FROM  dbo.FPP_Invoice_Revenue
WHERE Till_Prev_Inv_Amt_In_USD / 0.0285714286 = 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is strange to me that it is not using and index scan as [SOW_Number] is part of the PK. According to a comment an index scan would be reported as a table scan since it is a clustered index.

Could add an index on [SOW_Number] as suggest by Max (+1).

Putting [SOW_Number] first in the PK might help but doing that to table with 83,423,460 rows is not something I would jump into.

```
 UPDATE FPP_Temp_Revenue
 SET    Till_Prev_Inv_Amt = Till_Prev_Inv_Amt_In_USD / 0.0285714286,
        Cur_Inv_Amt       = Cur_Inv_Amt_In_USD       / 0.0285714286,
        YTD_Inv_Amt       = YTD_Inv_Amt_In_USD       / 0.0285714286
 WHERE  SOW_Number = '20014378'
```

You are not changing any index values so disable that index would have no effect

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_FPP_Invoice_Revenue] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Project_Code] ASC,
[SOW_Number] ASC,
[Invoice_No] ASC,
[Inv_Month] ASC,
[Inv_Year] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,       
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

8 minutes is not that bad.  Is this a query you need to run often?  If so a view might be more effective.